# rails undefined method controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using devise currently and I'm unable to allow users to create new accounts. I get the following error:

```
undefined method `controller_name' for #<Devise::Mailer:0xa58e760>
```

This occurs when rendering app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb

links.html.erb looks like:

```
1: <%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
2:     <%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
3: <% end -%>
```

has anyone else seen this error?

not sure if it makes any difference but I am using the app created by rails composer with twitter bootstrap, devise and cancan.

Answer (score 0):

Try `controller_path` or `params[:controller]` instead.

Comment: Instead of what? It'd be clearer (particularly for beginners) if you could add a bit more detail.

Comment: Instead of `controller_name` since that's what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

you can check controller name from parameters like,

```
if params[:controller].to_s != 'sessions'
```